# How can I get the toggle() method to stop repeating itself? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#add').click(function(){
    $('#list-area').append("<div class='list-item'><div class='box'><div class='dot'>&#x2713;</div></div></div>");

    $('.box').click(function(){
        $(this).children('.dot').toggle(200);
    });
});

});
```

Here's a jsfiddle link to all my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/96UVW/1/

This is a rudimentary replica of a checklist that I'm building.
Here's how it works (or supposed to work):

-Click the " + " to add an item. (This works fine.)

-Click the green box to check-off the item, or click it again to uncheck it...

...This misbehaves. What I want is that when a '.box' is clicked, it's respective '.dot' child element should toggle display once. But what happens is, the toggle repeats depending on how many items there are.

To clearly see my problem, add 5 items and click on their green boxes. The top will toggle 5 times, the next will toggle 4 times, etc.

Why does this occur? How can I adjust the code to make it behave the way I explained?

Comment: You're adding a *new* event handler for every `.box` element every time you click the `#add` element. Look up "event delegation".

Comment: @Blender Thanks, I'll definitely look into that. I'm really a beginner and I'm teaching myself, so any conceptual help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the event handler to only that element that you create:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#add').click(function(){

    var dot = $('<div>').addClass('dot').html('&#x2713;');
    var box = $('<div>').addClass('box').append(dot);

    $('#list-area').append($('<div>').addClass('list-item').append(box));

    box.click(function(){
      dot.toggle(200);
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: @Patrik --> Yes. The reason it is toggling over and over, is because every time you add the element, you are binding another toggle event to the elements that are already created.

Comment: @Guffa It worked! Awesome! Targeting only the element I create was exactly what I had in mind, but I had no idea how. Since I'm a beginner, I'm not really up on good coding habits, and this seems to be a simple and organized approach, so I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can check [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.box', function () {
        $(this).children('.dot').toggle(200);
    });
    $('#add').click(function () {
        $('#list-area').append("<div class='list-item'><div class='box'><div class='dot'></div></div></div>");
    });
});
```